# how display a jquery validate message inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am successfully validating a required field using jQuery Validate method. Everything works fine but I want to display the error message inside ia div tag which an option to make the error disappear after 10 or 20 sec of showing it, basically like a auto hide.

here is the markup I have created

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cForm").validate({
    rules: {
        PaymentMethod: {
            required: true
        }
        ,ShippingMethod: {
            required: true
        }
    },

    messages: {

        PaymentMethod: {
            required:" Select a payment method!"
        }
        ,ShippingMethod: " Select a shipping method!."
    }   

    });

});
</script>

<sytle="text/css">
 #ship-msg, #pay-msg {display:none; background:url("/image/req.gi") no-repeat left center transparent;}
 .msg { color:#000;}

</style>


<form id="cForm" method="post" action="/pay.html">
<div class="ship-options">
<label for="ShippingMethod">Shipping Method</label>
<select id="ShippingMethod" name="ShippingMethod" >
  <option value="">Choose Shipping Method</option>
  <option value"UPS-GROUND">UPS GROUND</option>
  <option value"UPS-1DAY">UPS 1DAY</option>
  <option value"UPS-2DAY">UPS 2DAY</option>
    </select>
    <div id="ship-msg><div class="msg"> // display the error messgae here </div>
</div>

<div class="pay-options">
<label for="PaymentMethod">Payment Method</label>    
<select id="PaymentMethod" name="PaymentMethod" >
  <option value="">Choose Paymenet Method</option>
  <option value"VISA">VISA</option>
  <option value"MASTERCARD">MASTERCARD</option>
  <option value"AMEX">AMERICAN EXPRESS</option>
</select>
 <div id="pay-msg><div class="msg"> // display the error messgae here </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Continue" id=" />

</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

and so when some clicks the continue button and if the methods are not selected display them display the respective divs and its message

I know i am missing something

Thanks and appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

1. You misspelled the opening `<style>` tag. Therefore `#ship-msg`, `#pay-msg` won't be hidden:

   `<sytle="text/css"> ... </style>`
2. Your script must be placed **after** jQuery has been loaded. That is at the end of your document. If you place it before the jQuery script is loaded, the browser won't recognize function calls like `$(document).ready()` and `$("#cForm").validate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the obvious mistakes (jQuery reference BEFORE the code and style tag mispelling) were simple oversights on your part and that you want to know how to make the appearing/disappearing happen. If you want to make the error appear and then go away after some time, when the validation fails call this function:

```
function ToggleErrorMessage(messageDiv) {
    messageDiv.toggle().delay(20000).toggle();
}
```

Which will turn the div on, wait 20 secs, and then turn it off. "messageDiv" is the div which you want to apply this to.

Comment: thanks for replaying. I tried like this but error is not displaying. I even removed display:none to see if its working but no luck

Comment: How hell can I new markup code I have to this post. i want to show my new code. please tell me how I can post the new code <br /> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strictly using your validate but this should help you on your way

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/qZkpH/21/)